# python, fix broken npy file. ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged

Tags: python, numpy

I run a program that saves data in a npy file every 20 seconds, but overwrites the old one, to update the file.

Yesterday after a day of data colection the program crashed, beacuse of a human error of somebody doing a keyboardinterupt at the wrong moment.

Now after loading the npy file I get the error message 
ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged

I already tried the

with open("test.npy", "rb") as npy:
    a = np.load(npy)

solution but the error remains.

What I think is going on is that there are lines missing in the npy file, but I don't know how to fix it. The npy file still has the size in MB it should have so there is defenitely something saved.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix my file and get the data that is in there?

Otherwise I loose a day of data.

Any help is very much appreciated!

Edit: Here one can find the broken file and an example of a good one that should be exactly the same except the numbers are different. http://perswww.kuleuven.be/~u0077049/

The shape is (1024, 3649)
The dtype is dtype('float64')

Comment: How much do you know about the data file? Do you know the dimensions and dtype of the array it is supposed to contain? Could you upload the array somewhere?

Comment: In the future you may want to think of modifying your program so that you save the data in a new file, then use os.rename() to overwrite the old file.  os.rename() is an atomic operation, and this will ensure that the old file is only overwritten once the new file is successfully created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [npy format is very simple](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/neps/npy-format.html). It starts with an ascii description of the data (data type, array size), followed by a flat binary dump. The header data is always a multiple of 16 bytes, which happens to be a multiple of the size of a float64 (8 bytes) as well.

In this example, the header is 80 bytes. In your case, you have to try.

```
import numpy as np

# write npy file
a = 10**np.array(np.linspace(-10, 10, 51), dtype=np.float64)
np.save('foo.npy', a)

# read back
b = np.fromfile('foo.npy', dtype=np.float64)
print(b[10:])
```

You have to use `reshape` to get in it in the correct (Fortran) array order.

I had a brief look at your files; the problem seems to be that the file is supposed to be 29892688 bytes but the broken file is 29892609, i.e. 79 bytes too short. If you pad the file (or the array that you read with the procedure above) with 79 bytes of zeros, it's likely that you can read it again.

Comment: When I read your reply I did not have my account details and then I forgot to reply, so sorry for my late reply, but you are without a doubt my hero Han-Kwang Nienhuys. All my data was saved. Leave It to the Dutch to solve things!